# Golang library to get the serial number and make of a laptop?

Tags: go

Want to know a way to get the serial number and make of a laptop using some golang code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No easy answer for this, as this is OS-specific. One option is to use `os/exec` package and parse command output (different command for Windows, Linux and OS X). For example to obtain serial number on:

- Windows: `wmic bios get serialnumber`
- Linux: `dmidecode -t system`
- OS X: `ioreg -l`

Then combined with Go code for OS X case:

```
out, _ := exec.Command("/usr/sbin/ioreg", "-l").Output() // err ignored for brevity
for _, l := range strings.Split(string(out), "\n") {
    if strings.Contains(l, "IOPlatformSerialNumber") {
        s := strings.Split(l, " ")
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", s[len(s)-1])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Working on what Pawel answered, I see a small optimization given that on my computer the information is on line 31 out of 21,980. I would return it as soon as it's found and break out of the for loop.

```golang
var serialNumber string
out, _ := exec.Command("/usr/sbin/ioreg", "-l").Output() // err ignored for brevity
for _, l := range strings.Split(string(out), "\n") {
    if strings.Contains(l, "IOPlatformSerialNumber") {
        s := strings.Split(l, " ")
        serialNumber = s[len(s)-1]
        break
    }
}
```

The previous answer works, but I don't like to go through 29,000 lines for nothing !